# What is this block in Minecraft's terrain.png?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is this block? Is it some development thing? I can't seem to find it. (It's right underneath the jungle plants as you can see)

[image]

Comment: Are you useing a texture pack for any chance?

Comment: @Ladineko yes looks like a texture pack to me, too.

Comment: @uncovery No that's in the vanilla terrain.png.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Command Block

That block is the Command Block, commonly used for server owners with server commands. It is not possible to break it unless you are in creative mode. It can't be normally crafted. Currently, it is not available in the creative mode inventory either.

[image: Interface of the Command Block.]

### Item Frame

The other block is an Item Frame. The Item Frame is craftable with 8 sticks and a leather in the middle. This is what the Item Frame looks like. [image: Multiple Item Frames]

This is how you make it.

[image: How to make the Item Frame]

[Images from Minecraft Wiki and Minecraft101 (dot) net]

Comment: FYI: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Command_Block

Comment: The item frame isn't actually a block, but instead an entity.

Answer (score 8):

The left one is the [Command Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block), which was already mentioned by @Bailey Rowland.

Just writing this for completeness, the right one is the [Item Frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame). The border of the item frame is the texture of birch wood plank, and the back uses that texture.

In fact, on the Minecraft Wiki there is [an image indicating what `terrain.png` represents](https://minecraft.wiki/w/File:TerrainGuide.png):

[image: terrian.png guide]

Here you can easily identify them.

---

Just FYI, the format of texture pack was changed since Minecraft 1.5, so the information is not strictly applicable for Minecraft 1.5 or above.

Comment: You have a good point.